# CKEditor multiple span tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

In ckeditor, instead of styles, I want to have classes for all styles. So I have used the following configuration.

```
config.coreStyles_bold = {
    element: 'span',
            attributes: { 'class': 'Bold' },
};
config.coreStyles_italic = {
    element: 'span',
    attributes: { 'class': 'Italic' },
};
```

The Bold and Italic classes are defined in my contentsCss file.

But suppose I have following text in my editor

**Sky is blue.**

If I apply Bold and then Italic on this. Then generated output is :

`<span class = 'Italic'> <span class = 'Bold'> Sky is blue </span> <span>`

i.e. two different tags for Bold and Italic are being generated.

Whereas I would like to have the following output :

`<span class= 'Bold Italic' > Sky is blue </span>`

Is it possible ? 
Note : I am using CKeditor 4.4.1

Comment: can you provide the file? I only see this in the minified version from ckeditor.

Comment: I am using a  minified version of ckeditor. So what should I be doing ?

Comment: O wow that's rough, there's no real negative side to just using the two spans for this situation, it'll work the same way as one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
// Only one core style for both elements
config.coreStyles_myStyle = {
element: 'span',
        attributes: { 'class': 'my-style' },
};
```

Then in the css

```
.my-style{
   font-weight:bold;
   font-style:italic;
 }
```

Comment: But, I am just over riding the existing Bold and Italic options in CKEditor.  So I cannot combine the two styles in one class.